# How to avoid memory leak using Linux list.h APIs

Tags: c, linux, list, memory-leaks

I am using linux list.h APIs and wondering if I had memory leak. 
The reason is below part of code allocate different memory addresses for each loop (line 40-41) but the addresses returned from line 56-57:cmd = list_entry(...) are the last address malloc-ed. Are free(cmd_ptr); list_del_init(&cmd_head); good enough?

Note: pay attention

```
 cmd = list_entry(pos, struct cmd_buf, list);
 printf("entry ptr: %p\n", cmd_ptr);
```

is returning the **same address**. See the screen output after the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "list.h" // locally copied to working dir  
// original http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/list.h

#define DEFAULT_SCRIPT_FILE "commands.txt"
#define BUFSIZE 256

typedef struct cmd_buf {
  char buf[BUFSIZE]; 
  struct list_head list;
} Cmd_buf; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
   script_xxx(); 
   return 0;  
}

int script_xxx(void)
{
    FILE *pfile = 0;
    char file_name[BUFSIZE], tmp_buf[BUFSIZE]; 
    struct list_head cmd_head, *pos = 0;
    Cmd_buf *cmd_ptr, *cmd;
    int i = 0, max_loops = 3;  

    strncpy(file_name, DEFAULT_SCRIPT_FILE, sizeof(file_name)); 
    pfile = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if(pfile == NULL) {
          printf("Failed to open file %s\n", file_name); 
          return -1; 
    }   

    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&cmd_head);

    while (!feof(pfile)) { 
           if(fgets(tmp_buf, BUFSIZE, pfile)) { 
              cmd_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Cmd_buf));
              printf("malloc ptr: %p\n", cmd_ptr); 
              strncpy(cmd_ptr->buf, tmp_buf, sizeof(tmp_buf));   
              list_add_tail(&(cmd_ptr->list), &cmd_head);
           }
    }   
    fclose(pfile); 

    if(list_empty(&cmd_head)) { 
      printf("Command not found in %s\n", file_name); 
      return 0;  
    }   

    for (i = 0; i < max_loops; i++ ) { 
         printf("\n\nRunning commands loop %d\n", i); 
         list_for_each(pos, &(cmd_head)) {
             cmd = list_entry(pos, struct cmd_buf, list);
             printf("entry ptr: %p\n", cmd_ptr); 
             if(cmd) printf("    Runing cmd in loop %d: %s", i, cmd->buf);
         }
    }   

    if(i == max_loops) 
       printf("\nCompleted all %d loops\n", i); 
    else if(i < max_loops) 
       printf("\nCommand failed at loop %d\n", i); 

    if(cmd_ptr) free(cmd_ptr);  
    list_del_init(&cmd_head); 
    printf("freeing ptr: %p\n", cmd_ptr); 
    return 0;  
}




./a.out
malloc ptr: 0x2df8250
malloc ptr: 0x2df8370
malloc ptr: 0x2df8490


Running commands loop 0
entry ptr: 0x2df8490
    Runing cmd in loop 0: command a b c 
entry ptr: 0x2df8490
    Runing cmd in loop 0: command x y z 
entry ptr: 0x2df8490
    Runing cmd in loop 0: command yyy


Running commands loop 1
entry ptr: 0x2df8490
    Runing cmd in loop 1: command a b c 
entry ptr: 0x2df8490
    Runing cmd in loop 1: command x y z 
entry ptr: 0x2df8490
    Runing cmd in loop 1: command yyy


Running commands loop 2
entry ptr: 0x2df8490
    Runing cmd in loop 2: command a b c 
entry ptr: 0x2df8490
    Runing cmd in loop 2: command x y z 
entry ptr: 0x2df8490


Completed all 3 loops
freeing ptr: 0x935490
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use 'valgrind your_program' to check whether there is memory leakage.
2. INIT_DLIST_HEAD()?? Should it be INIT_LIST_HEAD()?
3. In your program, cmd_ptr is a pointer to a cmd_buf, and is only used in the insertion loop. It is unnecessary to free cmd_ptr in the end, because the object it points to has been inserted into the list. It should be freed together with other objects in list.
4. You should use a loop to free objects in the list iteratively.
   For example:

   while(!list_empty(cmd_head)){
       cmd = list_next_entry(cmd_head, list);
       __list_del_entry(&cmd->list);
       free(cmd);
   }